# How to check for wrong datetime entries (python/pandas)?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have an excel dataset containing datetime values of worked hours entered by employees. Now that the end of the year is near they want to report on it, however it is full of wrong entries. Thus I need to clean it.

Herebelow some examples of wrong entries.

What would be your approach when facing such datasets?

I first converted date column to datetime using `df['Shiftdatum'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Shiftdatum, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce')`

In below's sampledata it shows a NaT

How do I filter out these NaT's including the row's index?

```
[Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2019-03-11 00:00:00'),
 NaT,
 Timestamp('2019-03-12 00:00:00')
```

Initial sample data:

```
{0: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 1: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 2: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 3: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 4: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 5: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 6: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 7: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 8: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 9: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 10: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 11: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 12: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 13: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 14: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 15: '2019-03-11 00:00:00',
 16: '33/11/2019',
 17: '2019-03-12 00:00:00',
 18: '2019-03-12 00:00:00',
 19: '2019-03-12 00:00:00'}
```

Comment: Look at: https://www.winwaed.com/blog/2019/08/07/python-data-validation-date-time/ or https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/200634/program-to-check-if-a-date-is-valid-or-not

Comment: You'll need to handle the outliers, not sure if there is a one hit solution. How are employees entering data, excel?

Comment: @Datanovice yes excel, quite an odd scenario I know...

Comment: Not that odd, if no data validation in place it will always have errors I've managed upward of 6k employees in terms of time sheets. What have you tried so far? One solution would be to read in the excel and then turn the outliers to null values and forward fill

Comment: @Datanovice I updated the post, could you answer on this?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df.Shiftdatum, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce').dropna()` for dropping the nat, `df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.Shiftdatum, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce').isna(),'Shiftdatum']` for filtering them.. ??

Comment: @anky_91 thanks, it does the trick. But now I want to see the value behind the nat in order to correct it. Would u know how?

Comment: @Luukv93 yes, that would be possible i think, can you add a sample data for which I can test it and replicate the question? (the current data has just NaT, it would be better if you can create a series with invalid dates and post an expected output in the question) thanks

Comment: @anky_91 I don't think there is a one trick solution for dealing with very messy time series data, i think you could split it it out by using some regex, but I think manual intervention if the outliers are small say less than 100 is best.

Comment: @anky_91 I posted some more sample data

Comment: @Datanovice ohh i see now, fixing the invalid entries by code is not easy(and not recommended) , i thought identifying such cases was the requirement :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC,

you could handle this in a number of ways, you could use `pd.to_datetime(column,errors='coerce')` and assign your data to a new column

then with the new column, you could filter by `NaT` and get the unique outliers,

lets say this was the result :

```
data = ['033-10-2019', '100-03-2019','1003-03-2019','03-10-2019']

df = pd.DataFrame({'date_time' : data})
df['correct'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'],errors='coerce')
print(df)
       date_time    correct
0   033-10-2019        NaT
1   100-03-2019        NaT
2  1003-03-2019        NaT
3    03-10-2019 2019-03-10
```

now - we need to grab the unique NaT values in the `date_time` col

```
errors = df.loc[df['correct'].isnull()]['date_time'].unique().tolist()
out : ['033-10-2019', '100-03-2019', '1003-03-2019']
```

this is the boring bit, you'll need to go through and fix the errors and pass the correct value into a dictionary :

```
correct_dict = {'033-10-2019' : '03-10-2019', '100-03-2019' : '03-10-2019', '1003-03-2019' : '10-03-2019'}
```

then map the values back into your dataframe :

```
df['correct'] = df['correct'].fillna(pd.to_datetime(df['date_time'].map(correct_dict)))
print(df)
      date_time    correct
0   033-10-2019 2019-03-10
1   100-03-2019 2019-03-10
2  1003-03-2019 2019-10-03
3    03-10-2019 2019-03-10
```

If you just want to remove the NaT values you can just `dropna` whilst subsetting your column

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['correct'])
```

Comment: This was a lifesaver in figuring out an "Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp" error amongst 35,000 rows (and 280,000 DateTime fields). Ended up being only 8 fields with a negative date value.

Comment: @Adam I'm happy this solution helped, congrats on 1k!

Answer (score 2):

> How do I filter out these NaT's including the row's index?

if the requirement is to find out the invalid date entries, you can try `series.isna()` after `pd.to_datetime()` with [`series where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d,orient='index',columns=['Shiftdatum'])
#d is the dictionary in the question
```

---

```
s=pd.to_datetime(df.Shiftdatum, format='%Y-%m-%d', errors='coerce').isna()
e=df.Shiftdatum.where(s).dropna()
```

---

```
16    33/11/2019
```